# Calling ServiceBase.OnStart and OnStop... same instance?

Tags: c#, windows-services

So I've got a Windows service written in c#. The service class derives from `ServiceBase`, and starting and stopping the service calls instance methods `OnStart` and `OnStop` respectively. Here's SSCE of the class:

```
partial class CometService : ServiceBase
{
    private Server<Bla> server;
    private ManualResetEvent mre;
    public CometService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }       
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        //starting the server takes a while, but we need to complete quickly
        //here so let's spin off a thread so we can return pronto.
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                server = new Server<Bla>();
            }
            finally
            {
                mre.Set()
            }
        })
        {
            IsBackground = false
        }.Start();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        //ensure start logic is completed before continuing
        mre.WaitOne();
        server.Stop();
    }
}
```

As can be seen, there's quite a lot of logic that requires that when we call `OnStop`, we're dealing with the same instance of `ServiceBase` as when we called `OnStart`.

Can I be sure that this is the case?

Comment: Put that in an answer with a reference and I'll hand you the points!

Comment: Um. Are you sure you want to do `IsBackground = true`? If you return from `OnStart` and only background threads are running, the process might be shut down - so it's only by luck/timing (that that thread has already made sufficient forward progress to launch the `Server`) that the service stays up.

Comment: Indeed... actually it isn't like that in the actual code, so please ignore. Will fix up the example though.

Comment: IsBackground = true is fine. The service will be kept in memory until OnStop is called - that is what being a service means. If your OnStart and OnStop methods were empty the process would still stay in memory when started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look in the `Program.cs` class, you'll see code like the following:

```
private static void Main()
{
    ServiceBase.Run(new ServiceBase[]
                {
                    new CometService()
                });
}
```

That is, the instance is *created* by code within your own project. It's that one instance that all Service Manager calls (including `OnStart` and `OnStop`) are made against.

Answer (score 1):

I guess is the same instance. You can do a quick test adding a static field in the class to keep track of the reference to the object used in the OnStart and comparing it to the instance of the OnStop.

```
private static CometService instance = null;

protected override void OnStart(...)
{
    instance = this;
    ...
}

protected override void OnStop()
{
    object.ReferenceEquals(this, instance);
    ...
}
```